# How can I run code analysis the same as Android Studio performs on commit?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, code-analysis, lint

[image]

How can I run code analysis the same as Android Studio performs on commit?

I tried to use `Analyze` - `Inspect Code` feature - but it shows completely different warnings that I see during code analysis on commit.

Of course, I tried `Build` - `Make Project` - it also shows different warnings and even different errors.

So, it looks like Android Studio has 3 different sets of warnings & errors. And I can't find how I can run the third of them without attempt to commit changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based of the fact that every other day `Analyze` - `Inspect Code` shows different warnings in the same code, I can suggest that Lint is malfunctioning and doesn't show all warnings. But on the pre-commit check it shows all warnings for changed files.

Answer (score 6):

think that this "Code Analysis" is the default Android Studio inspection (`Analyze > Inspect Code`), as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspections.html) - different results might be the result of using different profiles. while you can also use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (also used in some Google libraries) or add [JaCoCo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) plugin to Gradle projects, which is Java Code Coverage for test builds.

Comment: There is no single warning on the on-commit code analysis that I can see on `Analyze` - `Inspect Code`. They are completely different.

Comment: I use standard configuration of the Android Studio. I haven't installed any custom plugins.

Comment: @Dmitry just tried, here I get results on `preCommit` and I cannot find anything hinting for alternate profiles/settings in `.idea/inspectionProfiles` ...and that these messages vary, is because Gradle build is something else than code inspection by the IDE; this is not even the regular Git `onPreCommit` hook (which also could be scripted). if there are no warnings at all, the scope might just be too narrow, eg. a single class or package; because when I commit a `.xml` file instead of a `.java` file, I get no results either. when directly running it... it gets more obvious what the scope is.

Comment: I see **many more** errors & warnings on pre-commit code analysis. And nothing on code inspection (I fixed everything there).

Comment: @Dmitry and which scope do you select there when manually running it? if there is eg. `uncommitted files` selected, while there is nothing to commit, this would also result in having no inspection scope, at all. while on `preCommit`, the scope is always defined by the files to commit.

Comment: The scope is the same. Changes in the changed files can be unrelated to the warnings - but they trigger pre-commit analysis. So, I see there what I can't see by `Inspect Code` of the same files.

Comment: there is a similar bug filed for AS on MacOS: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68022200 ...this would be the whole tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708 (using `3.1.4` on Linux here, which works as expected). canary channel releases (beta & rc) may occasionally have issues like that; if using such one, downgrading to a stable version might be the most leading.

Comment: I can see different types of warning & errors there. It doesn't look like an issue.

Comment: @Dmitry the only two possible reasons are a) different scopes or b) different inspection profiles. per default there is a default profile and a profile per project: I only see the option to chose the profile when manually running the inspection; the `preCommit` might use the per project profile.

Comment: But I didn't change any profiles. I even don't know how I can do that.

Comment: The errors & warnings from pre-commit code analysis look completely different - they're more like compiler errors & warnings - not hits from lint.

Comment: Lint is so buggy that it even finds different warnings on every try. My standard procedure: fix 150 warnings using `Inspect Code`, fix 50 additional warnings on pre-commit code analysis, fix 5 new-appeared warnings using `Inspect Code` (they are not caused by changes on pre-commit check), leave few remaining errors on pre-commit check that are not errors at all.